# Create a native SDK using Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-module

I'm with a task but I don't know how to start this
I searched a lot, there are very few articles about that, but none of then worked

I need to create a SDK (library aar, framework) in flutter to be used on native code

If you guys can help me with this 3 points I'm sure I can continue and implement all that I need

1. What I should create to be able to link a Flutter SDK in native code ? Should it be a module, a plugin or a ffi-plugin ?
2. On the flutter SDK how can I ask for a token and follow start a flutter screen inside the native host application ?
3. How should I do on the host application to import the SDK made on flutter and interact with it ?

If anyone could me help with this I will really really be grateful

Comment: Are you trying to write a Flutter library which will be used with a Java/Kotlin Android app or Obj-C/Swift iOS app? Asking a native Kotlin/Swift developer to add in the full Flutter framework just to add in your library is a rather large burden, i.e. download and setup the full Flutter framework/environment as Flutter sits on top of the platform SDK.

Comment: Yes, I want to write a flutter library to be used in a Java/Kotlin android or Obj-C/Swift iOS App
There's no way to compile this to an aar / .xcframework and run as native ?
To do that all projects that will import my lib will need to setup full flutter env ?

Comment: So I was able to find: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app and the details here: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup state that at least on Android the Flutter module AAR would be stand-alone (not require Flutter SDK). For iOS see: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#option-b---embed-frameworks-in-xcode Just be aware that the end developer may need to do a number of steps to add in a Flutter module.